# Can I pass more than one object value in context using react-apollo graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Can I pass more than one object value in context using react-apollo graphql
like below code of server.js . If yes then how?

```js
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), apolloExpress(request => ({
    schema: ncSchema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: { token:getTokenFromRequest(request), user:getUserFromrequestToken(request) },
  })));
```

Comment: The code you posted should be ok

Comment: but not working. When i login. if remove , user:getUserFromrequestToken(request) then works

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: graphql:1 POST http://localhost:4000/graphql 500 (Internal Server Error)
SignInFormContainer.js:32 Error: Network error: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:31)
    at QueryManager.js:129
    at <anonymous>

when sign in. if remove , user:getUserFromrequestToken(request) then no problem.

Comment: And at graphql console below error
(node:1180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatError' of undefined
(node:1180) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zer
o exit code.
(node:1180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatError' of undefined

Comment: Its working now. When i have changed the order of called function in context. like user:getUserFromrequestToken(request),token:getTokenFromRequest(request)
I think object value received as token, user i.e. right to left

Comment: issue resolved !!!!!!